# Javascript onclick, throws an uncatchable exception

Tags: javascript, html, exception, dom-events

I have this piece of code but for some reason it doesn't work. I have tried to look at the Google Chrome Javascript console and it looks like it is throwing some sort of exception. But when the exception is thrown, the page refreshes so I don't get to see the exception. Can some one please help?

```
            <section class="form_section">
                <label for="tag">Tags(Click to select)</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter tag name" id="tag_input" class="tag_input"/>
                <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addTag()" title="Click to add tag"/>
                <section id="tags" class="tags"></section>
            </section>


var tags = new Array();
        
        function addTag()
        {
            var value = document.getElementById("tag_input").value;
            if(value.length > 0)
            {
                tags[value] = value;
                var temp = "<a href=\"\" onclick=\"removeTag(this); return false;\" class=\"tag_item\">" + value + "</a>";
                document.getElementById("tags").innerHTML += temp;
                document.getElementById("tag_input").value = "";
            }
        }
        function removeTag(obj)
        {
            console.log(obj);
        }
```

Comment: Is your javascript being called after the DOM is loaded?

Comment: why are you escaping quotes when you don't need to? that could be causing the error.

Comment: I don't see any problem: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/4nqXK/

Comment: @kennypu what do you mean "when you don't need to"? Those look escaped correctly to me.

Comment: Yes I am calling it after the dom loads.

Comment: @Xymostech nvm, I didn't see that that whole statement was a string, I thought I was looking at html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correction

`condole.log(obj);` must be `console.log(obj);` and put `return false;` so execution will stop there.

If you don't want to add `return false;` then try adding link as below,

```
var temp = "<a href=\"Javascrip:void(0);\" onclick=\"removeTag(this); return false;\" class=\"tag_item\">" + value + "</a>";
```

`Javascrip:void(0);` will do that for you.

Comment: The code doesn't say `condole.log`...? (I didn't downvote, just confused)

Comment: I don't see any `condole.log` in the code and he did put `return false` after his code...

Comment: @Xymostech hey that is edited....so it does not mean down vote..? i read it before OP has edited...

Comment: @Derek code is edited at the moment when i was writting answer...i feel being quick to answer before question edit is enough for getting down voted..

Comment: @DubemEnyekwe hey leave it you say does it solved your problem or not..?

Comment: Sorry @DipeshParmar, I have no idea who did the down voting.

Comment: @DubemEnyekwe down vote does not matter...your problem is solved or not is main matter...tell me does it worked..?

Comment: @DipeshParmar - Actually I wasn't the only person who downvoted you, but hey, 2x `+10` - 2x `+2` = 16 reputation! :D And at least you should mention in your answer that it was only a typo.

Comment: @DubemEnyekwe always welcome brother.... +1 for you to accept that you had condole.log....

Comment: Don't use a broken A element, use an appropriate element (e.g. button). The use of grouping brackets 

with `void` is competely unnecessary, it's an operator, not a function. Where a dummy link used (not recommended, use a styled span or button), all that is required is a minimal statement, so `href='javascript:;'` will suffice. But please don't use it.